# can't handle a redirect

Tags: redirect

I've been trying to redirect a page but with no success. 
My purpose is to redirect `example.com/me/name` to `example.com/me?n=name`
I've tried with `add_rewrite_rule`, write conditions in .htaccess, but nothing worked.
Any clue?

Edit:
The full htaccess code is this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  # Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml

  # Remove browser bugs (only needed for really old browsers)
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
  BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
  Header append Vary User-Agent
</IfModule>


## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

Edit 2:
The code for redirect I was trying to use is this:

```
#RewriteRule (http://example.com/me/*) http://example.com/me?n=$1
```

Edit 3:
The "name" in the code does not stay the same, it is variable depending on person. It can be Ash, George, Mike, whatever.

Comment: Can you post your `.htaccess` code?

Comment: @Steve - I added it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

use [This Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-301-redirects/)

Or Write this code on top of htacces file:

```
Redirect 301 /oldfile.htm http://example.net/newfile.htm
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try the following? Also make sure your Rewrite Module is "uncommented" from `apache.conf` and/or `php.ini` depending on your configuration.

```
#permanently redirect from example.com/me/name domain to example.com/me?n=name
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example/me\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ www.example.com/?n=name/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hello and first of all thank you for trying to help me! Unfortunately it is not working, I'm not sure why myself. I posted my example commented as I decided to comment it if it's not working in order not to break something by mistake.

Comment: About the uncomment part I mean in `php.ini` or `apache.conf` file, by default the Mod Rewrite is turned off, and if you didn't turned it on it won't work, can you tell me what's your setup like is it localhost or hosting and are you using Wampp, Xampp, Lampp etc.. Thanks!

Comment: Hello again! I'm not sure to tell you details about the config because I work via an FTP account and the files are hosted by a company. I'm sure the mod rewrite is turned on as other redirects are working fine.

Comment: Oh, by the way! With "name" in the link I meant to say that "name" is variable. It is like "JohnK" or "SmithA" or something like this. Not actually "name"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18436941/php-redirect-with-variable
Check this one

Comment: Hello and thank you for the suggestion! It is somewhat useful but being a Wordpress site, I'm afraid it will not quite work well because when I try to access example.com/name/John (for example) it will land me on a 404 error not found page because it is looking for the page with the name "John". I need to make the redirect before the Wordpress checks the link somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Kinal Nagarkar that there is a simple plugin for this. My personal Favorite is [Redirection](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/). It not only allows direct URL redirects, but also REGEX and give you a counter to monitor how often it is used. (There are also some other features that I don't personally use, but I'm sure are useful).

Either way, there are at least two plugins that you could use that are pretty light weight and don't require you to reinvent the wheel for a single redirect.

While changing your .htaccess might operate faster, please consider usability as another important factor too.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for the suggestion. I'd like to say that I tried using `Redirection` but with no success unfortunately. I didn't find much info on their page on how to use it either so I gave up trying at some point. Any chance you could point me to some information I could read and use? I'm not necessarily asking for a "ready to go" solution but at least some article or place to start reading so I can understand more about it. Thanks! P.S. I don't understand how to use it with specific parameter or RegExp

Comment: unfortunately after some trial and error myself I found the REGEX in `Redirection` to be a bit wonky. I did get an error where it would replace multiple times... that was interesting. In the end I haven't found any specific documentation about how the REGEX is intended to work in this plugin. One other thing I noticed in my trials was that the plugin I tested with was hijacking some of my redirects, specifically /me/*

Comment: I tried the REGEX in `Redirection` a bit myself and found some odd results. I tried using your `me/name` example but found the theme had overridden that and resulted in no effect. I tried a few others and with no good results. Apparently `Redirection` isn't very good (or hasn't enough documentation) for REGEX + replacement ($1) usage. But in my experience is still great for simpler redirects. Sorry this isn't much good for your exact usage.